# How to insert documents in a loop?

Tags: meteor

I am iterating over a moment-range daterange and trying to insert documents. I am getting the following error:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/carpool_events/insert' 
Error
 Error: Sorting not supported on Javascript code
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Object.LocalCollection._f._cmp     (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/selector.js?    5b3e1c2b868ef8b73a51dbbe7d08529ed9fb9951:251:13)
    at Object.LocalCollection._f._cmp     (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/selector.js?    5b3e1c2b868ef8b73a51dbbe7d08529ed9fb9951:226:36)
    at LocalCollection._f._cmp (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/selector.js?5b3e1c2b868ef8b73a51dbbe7d08529ed9fb9951:218:33)
    at _func (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/sort.js?08a501a50f0b2ebf1d24e2b7a7f8232b48af9057:63:8), <anonymous>:1:51)
    at Function.LocalCollection._insertInSortedList     (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?7f5131f0f3d86c8269a6e6db0e2467e28eff6422:616:9)
    at Function.LocalCollection._insertInResults (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?7f5131f0f3d86c8269a6e6db0e2467e28eff6422:534:31)
    at LocalCollection.insert (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?7f5131f0f3d86c8269a6e6db0e2467e28eff6422:362:25)
    at m.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js?3ef9efcb8726ddf54f58384b2d8f226aaec8fd53:415:36)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata/livedata_connection.js?77dd74d90c37b6e24c9c66fe688e9ca2c2bce679:569:25
```

This is my loop with the insert. I have tested the loop by just writing to console.log instead of inserting and the loop works fine

```
    'click button.save-addEventDialogue': function(e, tmpl) {

          var start = Session.get("showAddEventDialogue_dateRangeStart");
          var end = Session.get("showAddEventDialogue_dateRangeEnd");
          var dateRange = moment().range(moment(start),moment(end));
          var dateLoopIncrement = moment().range(moment(start),moment(start).add('days',1));

          console.log(dateRange);
          console.log(dateLoopIncrement);

          // Loop through the date range
          dateRange.by(dateLoopIncrement, function(moment) {
            // Do something with `moment`
            var dateToSave = dateRange.start;  

        // Insert the record
            Carpool_Events.insert({
                       owner: Meteor.user().profile.name,
                       owner_id: Meteor.userId(),
                       original_owner: Meteor.user().profile.name,
                       original_owner_id: Meteor.userId(),
                       declined: 0,
                                  date: dateToSave.toDate()
                      });
            dateToSave.add('days',1);
         });            

         // Clear the Session
         Session.set("showAddEventDialogue_dateRangeStart","");
         Session.set("showAddEventDialogue_dateRangeEnd","");

         // Close the dialogue
         Session.set("showAddEventDialogue", false);
       }
```

What is the right way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `Sorting not supported on Javascript code` is a result of inserting a JavaScript function (!) into a collection -- for example, by doing something like `Carpool_Events.insert({x: function () { ... }});` JavaScript functions should not normally go into collections.

Somewhere in your code there is probably a typo where you are not calling a function (for example, writing `Meteor.userId` on the client instead of `Meteor.userId()`.) My guess would be that in the process of making your code run on the server, you coincidentally fixed or avoided this.

I wasn't able to visually find the problem in your code -- if I'm wrong, to make more progress it would be helpful to have a reproduction.

Comment: I could not reproduce this in a new project so I assume it is something that I am doing. In order for the inserts to work in this particular scenario I removed the sort condition in the client and left my sort condition just on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue occurs when doing a bulk inserts (inserts in a loop) from the client. What I ended up doing was using a Meteor.methods to execute the insert on the server side. This seemed to workaround whatever the issue of doing this on the client is.

I also realized that I don't need to iterate over the dates using moment-range. Instead i just use moment to get the difference in days and iterate over that.

JS code in the client:

```
'click button.save-addEventDialogue': function (e, tmpl) {
  var start = moment(Session.get("showAddEventDialogue_dateRangeStart"));
  var end = moment(Session.get("showAddEventDialogue_dateRangeEnd"));
  var days = end.diff(start, 'days');
  var count = 0;
  var dateToSave = moment(start);

  // Loop through the date range
  for (count; count <= days; count++) {
    Meteor.call('bulkInsertCarpoolEvent', Meteor.user(), dateToSave.toDate());
    dateToSave.add('days', 1);
  };

  // Clear the Session
  Session.set("showAddEventDialogue_dateRangeStart", "");
  Session.set("showAddEventDialogue_dateRangeEnd", "");

  // Close the dialogue
  Session.set("showAddEventDialogue", false);

  }
```

On the server:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.methods({
    bulkInsertCarpoolEvent: function (user, date) {

      return Carpool_Events.insert({
        owner: user.profile.name,
        owner_id: this.userId,
        original_owner: user.profile.name,
        original_owner_id: this.userId,
        declined: 0,
        date: date
      });

    }
  });
});
```